# Why don't my functions have common parameters?

Tags: function, powershell, reflection, parameters

I'm trying to write some code that requires examining the functions metadata and processes some other data based on the command's parameters. In the process, I've discovered some *really* strange behavior that I can't figure out.

I have a function in a psm1 script module, and it's loaded by importing a neighboring psd1 module manifest that declares it as a nested module. I've declared 14 parameters on it explicitly. When I `Get-Command` and examine the `Parameters`, I can see it has 23 parameters. 14 are mine; the rest are [common parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters).

```
PS> (Get-Command Install-MyFunctionFromModule).Parameters.Count
23
PS> (Get-Command Install-MyFunctionFromModule).Parameters.keys
MyParameter1
MyParameter2
MyParameter3
MyParameter4
MyParameter5
MyParameter6
MyParameter7
MyParameter8
MyParameter9
MyParameter10
MyParameter11
MyParameter12
MyParameter13
MyParameter14
Verbose
Debug
ErrorAction
WarningAction
ErrorVariable
WarningVariable
OutVariable
OutBuffer
PipelineVariable
```

(My functions's name *does* start with `Install-`. My parameters don't end with numbers, though. These are just dummy placeholders because I didn't want to use the real names.)

This is kind of expected. Functions are supposed to have common parameters.

But in order to test my code that deals with the parameters, I tried creating a test module. Here's what it looks like:

**`testfun.psm1`**:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

function test-noparams() {
    Write-Host 'None'
}

function test-differentnamedparams([string]$hello, [switch]$bye) {
    Write-Host "names that don't conflict with common params"
}
```

Then when I import the module, neither functions have any common parameters:

```
PS> Import-Module .\testfunc.psm1
PS> (Get-Command test-differentnamedparams).Parameters.Count
2
PS> (Get-Command test-differentnamedparams).Parameters | Format-Table -AutoSize

Key   Value
---   -----
hello System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
bye   System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata

PS> (Get-Command test-noparams).Parameters.Count
0
```

I've tried a few things to see if they made a difference:

- Exporting the functions explicitly using `Export-ModuleMember`
- Use a manifest that imports the script module as a `NestedModule`
- Using a script and including it via `. .\testfunc.ps1` instead of a module
- Defining the function directly in the shell

None of them changed anything.

What determines whether or not a function has common parameters or not? What could cause them not to?

Comment: That's good to know, thanks - it would indeed be more helpful to be warned at function _definition_ time. I've added the information to the answer. If you decide to report an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues), feel free to add a link to it to my answer. I've cleaned up my other comments here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Only [*advanced* functions or scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced) support [common parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters).**

The ***explicit* way to make a script/function an advanced function** is to decorate its `param(...)` block with the **`[CmdletBinding()]` attribute**.

However, as [jpmc26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394393/jpmc26) himself discovered, **use of per-parameter `[Parameter()]` attributes *implicitly* makes a script or function an advanced one**.

- However, note that per-parameter attributes *other* than `[Parameter()]` - such as `[AllowNull()]` or `[Alias()]` - by themselves do *not* make an script/function and advanced function.

---

An **easy way to discover whether a given script/function is advanced** (supports common parameters) is to **pass its name to `Get-Help`**:

```
# Define a NON-advanced function - no [CmdletBinding()] or [Parameter()] attributes.
PS> function foo { param([string] $bar) 'hi' }; Get-Help foo

NAME
    foo

SYNTAX
    foo [[-bar] <string>]  


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

```
# Define an ADVANCED function EXPLICITLY - note the [CmdletBinding()] attribute
# BEFORE the param(...) block.
PS> function foo { [CmdletBinding()] param([string] $bar) 'hi' }; Get-Help foo

NAME
    foo

SYNTAX
    foo [[-bar] <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

```
# Define an ADVANCED function IMPLICITLY - note the [Parameter(Mandatory)] attribute 
# FOR PARAMETER $bar.
PS> function foo { param([Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $bar) 'hi' }; Get-Help foo

NAME
    foo

SYNTAX
    foo [[-bar] <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

---

#### Optional reading: pitfall: name collisions with common parameters

As of PSv5.1:

[jpmc26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394393/jpmc26) has also discovered that if you accidentally declare a parameter whose name clashes with a common parameter name, you don't get an error when you *define* the function, but only later when you *invoke it*, which includes passing it to `Get-Help`:

```
# Define advanced function that mistakenly names a a parameter for
# a common parameter:
PS> function foo { [CmdletBinding()] param([string] $Verbose) 'hi' }
# NO error is reported at this point.

# Later invocation of the function, including introspection of its parameters
# when you pass it to Get-Help, then surfaces the problem:
PS> Get-Help foo
Get-Help : A parameter with the name 'Verbose' was defined multiple times for the command.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Help foo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Get-Help], MetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterNameAlreadyExistsForCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```